# AutoPilot Install Behind Proxy

Tags: juju, proxy, openstack-autopilot

So root cause in juju is bootstrap image gets copied to the baremetal but does not include the proxy setting so the curl commands are failing.

Workaround is done view staging the code instead:

```
juju bootstrap --upload-tools --debug
```

**Does the openstack-install script support a similar model to stage the software locally so autopilot works in similar way?**

As a note the PXE boot image from MaaS does include the right proxy settings via the MaaS GUI settings but the second reboot with the image JuJu DDs to the local disk does not.

---

I'm trying to install AutoPilot on 14.04.3 while behind a proxy.  I'm able to get MaaS and all my nodes setup but its stalling at the JuJu section as shown.

[image]

I'm currently using apt & env proxy settings.

---

I've now added the following edits as a **start** to getting it working:

1. First add the following file: /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh for persistent proxy

   sudo vi /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh
2. Now add the following lines with your specific proxy address and port:

   export http_proxy=http://:/
   export ftp_proxy=http://:/
   export no_proxy=localhost,127.0 0 1
   export HTTP_PROXY=http://:/
   export FTP_PROXY=http://:/
   export https_proxy=http://:/
   export HTTPS_PROXY=http://:/
3. Now allow sudo to inherit these values whenever you use "sudo":

   sudo visudo
4. Now add the following lines below existing Defaults:

   Defaults  env_keep += "http_proxy"
   Defaults  env_keep += "https_proxy"
   Defaults  env_keep += "HTTP_PROXY"
   Defaults  env_keep += "HTTPS_PROXY"
   Defaults  env_keep += "FTP_PROXY"
   Defaults  env_keep += "ftp_proxy"
   Defaults  env_keep += "no_proxy"

Comment: The Juju proxy failure you're seeing is https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1515289